# Build solution programmatically with its solution configuration

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, build-process, projects-and-solutions

I have a function to build a big solution (100+ projects)

```
public static bool BuildSolution()
{
    bool result = false;
    try
    {
        string solutionPath = @"C:\path\to\my\solution.sln";

        ProjectCollection pc = new ProjectCollection();

        Dictionary<string, string> GlobalProperty = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        GlobalProperty.Add("Configuration", "Debug");
        GlobalProperty.Add("Platform", "Any CPU");
        GlobalProperty.Add("OutputPath", @"bin\Debug\");

        BuildParameters bp = new BuildParameters(pc);
        BuildRequestData BuidlRequest = new BuildRequestData(solutionPath, GlobalProperty, "4.0", new string[] { "Build" },null);
        BuildResult buildResult = BuildManager.DefaultBuildManager.Build(bp, BuidlRequest);

        if (buildResult.OverallResult == BuildResultCode.Success)
        {
            result = true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Build Failed: " + e.ToString());
    }
    return result;          
}
```

Is there a way to use the solution configuration set within visual studio to prevent some project to be builded?

[image: solution configuration]

changes made on this form does not affect the .sln file and so my function keep build everything

Comment: For me, this code results in success if and only if the solution I'm attempting to build is already built. I.e. If I clean the target solution with VS then I get a failure result. The build result object contains no exceptions or useful information so I'm left guessing that clean removes some required dependency that VS knows about but the default build manager does not. Any help/comments?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new solution configuration using the configuration manager. In this new configuration you can only select the projects you need to build.

And for building using this configuration, you can change your program as

```
GlobalProperty.Add("Configuration", "NewConfigurationName");
```

[image: New configuration using Configuration manager]
Hope this is what you are looking for!!!

Comment: i alreay do it, but it doesn't work. the solution build configurations are not saved into .sln file and i don't know how to read them

Comment: Visual Studio actually stores the solution's build configuration in the solution file itself. If you open the "*.sln" file in a text editor, There is a section called "GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms)". Do you see the new configuration in this section?

Comment: yes, but my script build works only if i manually remove those projects from the solution... can't understand why